# Why are decimal fractions (vertically aligned along their dots in a table) left justified when adding long text in another row?

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

I want decimal fractions to be vertically aligned along their dots in a table environment. For this purpose, I use the `r@{.}l` command behind `\begin{tabular}{...}` (see MWE). This works well if there are only decimal fractions and short text (using the `\multicolumn` command) in the table. However, if I add longer text by the same technique in other rows, suddenly the decimal fractions become left justified.

How can I keep all content in a column centered? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabular}{lr@{.}l}
\hline
\hline
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{header} \\
\hline
row 1    & 0&1234                     \\
row 2    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text}   \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Correct display}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabular}{lr@{.}l}
\hline
\hline
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{header}                  \\
\hline
row 1    & 0&1234                                      \\
row 2    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{here's some longer text} \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Wrong display}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is what all output should look like:

[image]

This is what it looks like at the moment (decimal fraction left aligned):
[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn` does not extend the width of both columns but only the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `S`-columns of package [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering % Don't use center in floats!
\begin{tabular}{lS}
\hline
\hline
         & {header} \\
\hline
row 1    & 0.1234                     \\
row 2    & {text}   \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Correct display}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS}
\hline
\hline
         & {header}                  \\
\hline
row 1    & 0.1234                                      \\
row 2    & {here's some longer text} \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Wrong display}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1][image: Table 2]

Please read [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) if you want to fine-tune the result.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful answer! This is exactly what I was looking for and solves my problem.

Comment: On a second look, it does solve the centering problem, but adding more rows with decimal fractions, they aren't aligned along their dots anymore ...?

Comment: @saoirse86 I can add more rows with decimal centering without any problem, e.g., `row 3    & 17.89 \\ row 4    & 123.987 \\ ` Maybe you've added numbers that are not suitable for the defaults of the package. In this case adjust the settings e.g. declare `table-figures-decimal` or `table-figures-integer` or `table-number-alignment` or `table-format` or …

Comment: I found the mistake: I wrote lower-case s instead of capital S behind `\begin{tabular}`. This changes the alignment of decimal fractions.